# What can cause SQL Server encountered error 0x80070218 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process Error?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

This error persists on any full-text queries. I have researched and found several documents with promising solutions only to find they do not work. The first thing I found was, the Daemon and the SQL service need to run under the same account. I tried to move the Daemon to the same account the SQL service was using. No joy.  So I changed the account on both to a SQLAdmin account we had setup.  Both services start and run without issue. We changed the SQL Server Agent to run under this account. SQL is running. There have been no complaints about the server since we made this change yesterday. Queries (not the full-text ones) run fine. Is it possible that there is a permission that is required that this account does not have? I haven't been able to find anything on that. The same problem persists, however. The error itself suggests that we run the

```
sp_fulltext_service'restart_all_fdhosts'
```

but this command returns the same error.

```
Select * From sys.dm_fts_fdhosts;
```

Returns no rows.

I have rebuilt the catalog and the full-text index both with the wizard and manually. No Joy.  The error persists. We have of course re-booted the server, restarted services and checked the SQL Config to find anything that looks remotely affiliated with full-text searching.

Everything seems to point to the FDRHost process. If this is synonymous with the SQL Full-Text Daemon Launcher (this is my understanding), it is running on the server under the previously mentioned account.

SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

I would appreciate a document to troubleshoot this issue or even more grandly, a direct indication of the issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 went out of support some years ago, I doubt you are going to get much help. Can you show the message from the SQL Server error log?

Comment: @Charlieface Nothing in the log. Thank you.

Comment: Full message from a query: Msg 30046, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server encountered error 0x80070218 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process. Make sure that the FDHost process is running. To re-start the FDHost process, run the sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts' command or restart the SQL Server instance.

Comment: Weird, are you sure you checked the right logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out.  The original installation of the server was flawed.  While the services were in the Microsoft Service Center, the FDHost was not in the services of the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  No wonder it couldn't connect.  This is an old server and was the one that I was given to host the application. I have moved the DB to another server that was correctly configured, and my issues disappeared. If anyone else has this problem, please check the configuration Manger to make sure the service is present. Thank you to everyone who read this issue.